# How to give alert message in servlet and redirected it to jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

i am developing some kind of pubsub application,so when a user subscribe to particular entity
then he receive a alert for successful subscription and redirect on the same page.

Comment: can you provide a little more detail here, any technical specifications or limitations, and format this in the type of a question? :)

Comment: suppose i have 10 different video categories and i want to subscribe with one or more category,when i submit subscribe to particular category then i want to receive a alert message for subscription

Answer (score 3):

**In Servlet**

```
session.setAttribute("Login_Expired","Expired") ;
response.sendRedirect("jsp/page.jsp");
```

**In JSP**

```
<%
String strExpired = (String) session.getAttribute("Login_Expired");
if (strExpired.equals("Expired")){     
out.print("alert('Password expired, please update your password..');");
}      
%>
```

Comment: It's throwing a nullPointException because it's unable to process the jsp.

Comment: what if he wants to log in using different user?

Answer (score 1):

Add an attribute in request from servlet and forward request to jsp on jsp use following

```
request.setAttribute("subscribed",true);
```

on jsp , in javascript

```
if(${subscribed == 'true'}){
  alert("Peep Peep..");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In servlet

```
String strExpired = (String) session.getAttribute("Login_Expired");
response.sendRedirect("jsp/page.jsp");
```

In jsp

```
<%
String strExpired = (String) session.getAttribute("Login_Expired");
out.print("alert('Password expired, please update your password..');");
%>
```